# BehaviorSubject of a type in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I have a model User.

I want to create a BehaviorSubject of type User as below:

```
 private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<User>({});
```

With this statement I'm getting the following error:

```
  Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'
```

Could anyone help me how define a BehaviorSubject of type User

Comment: Show how your interface/class `User` looks like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `User` type. `{}` is an initial value which doesn't follow the schema/type of `User`.
Incase, you want to pass an empty value use `null` except `{}`

Answer (score 6):

That’s because `{}` is an object that doesn’t have the same properties as `User` (it’s an empty object in fact).

You can by pass this by casting `{}` to `any`:

```
new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as any);
```

Comment: Why not `new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as User);` instead of `new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as any);`

Answer (score 3):

`new BehaviorSubject<User>({})` with this you have passed an initial value for the `BehaviorSubject`. Cause `{}` has no type detection, you get error.

You need to pass an `User` type. Provide properties for that type in the `{}` like

```
private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<User>({ /* properties */ });
```

If you don't need initial value. you can use `ReplaySubject` with replay count set to `1`

```
new ReplaySubject<User>(1)
```

This will provide same functionality without initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `User` type has some must have properties. Hence an empty `{}` object is not assignable as a instance of `User`

For example the below `User` definition is not same as `{}`:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}
```

Changing the above to conditional properties `?` will allow assigning an empty object `{}` as `user`.

Example:

```
interface User {
  name?: string;
  address?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) requires an initial value :

> A Subject that requires an initial value and emits its current value to new subscribers

The given initial value (`{}` in your case) is not compatible with your `User` type, which probably has some required fields.

So create a user :

```
const user: User = [...];
private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<User>(user);
```

If you don't have an initial value, you might choose a [ReplaySubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the value (which satisfies the "User" model type) instead of "{}"

For E.g. if your user model is like this:

```
export interface User {
    name: string;
    id: string;
}
```

Then your behavior subject will be like:

```
private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<User>({ 
     name: 'xyz',
     id: 'xyz'
});
```

or

You can make all the properties in User model optional like this:

```
export interface User {
    name?: string;
    id?: string;
}
```

Comment: we can use new BehaviorSubject<User|null>(null)